# Does a USB-C dock connected to an external display leverage display link or a native graphics driver?

Tags: display, dock

I'm looking at [this](https://www.belkin.com/uk/p/P-F4U093/) Belkin USB-C dock to use with a MacBook Pro 2017.

I'm aware there are some docks that use a display link driver that relies on the CPU to connect an external display via a USB connection. This works, but takes up part of the CPU capacity in doing it.

Does the dock above use a display link driver, or does it rely on the native graphics driver ?

Comment: What did the pre-sales support people say at Belkin?  Do the specs state that it uses DisplayLink?